# Azure EventGrid Subject vs EventType

Tags: event-handling, azure-eventgrid

The [Event Grid Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/edge/event-schemas) has two fields `subject` and `eventType` that can be used to filter the events that you want to handle using the [Event Subscription Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/subscription-creation-schema).  Other than `eventType` is an exact match string and a `subject` uses `beginsWith` or `endsWith` matching are there recommendations or best practices on when to use which field?

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are there recommendations or best practices on when to use which field?

I think the comment makes sense, you could refer to the doc - [Understand event filtering for Event Grid subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering).

[image]

[image]